# Importing a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Initially, I hadn't found the `range.copyValuesToRange()` so I had written this:

```
var rr = src.getRange(start_row, start_col, nrows, 1).getValues();
dst.getRange(start_row, start_col+1, nrows, 1).setValues(rr);
```

And I did similar stuff for larger ranges, so I reworked the above to this:

```
var rr = src.getRange(start_row, start_col, nrows, 1);
rr.copyValuesToRange(dst, start_col+1, start_col+1, start_row, start_row+nrows);
```

I am doing some basic logging to another sheet but I'm not seeing a lot of execution speed difference in them. The documentation says to do stuff in batches which is what I'm doing, but is there the extra overhead of doing a conversion to the arrays in both directions?

If there are lots of blank cells in the `src` range, how will these approaches impact the `dst` cell count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [`copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-options) (with option contentsOnly: true to match what you are currently doing), as the parameters of this method are more consistent with the rest of Apps Script. But this is just because of the aesthetics, not for performance reasons. The process of a script accessing spreadsheet data is so slow that any additional conversion that needs to be done should be negligible.

Blank cells are copied like any others, the blank state has no effect on how you use the methods. One reason I like `copyTo` is not having to spell out the coordinates of the destination: as the documentation says, only the top-left cell of the destination range is relevant. So, I would write a one-liner

```
src.getRange(start_row, start_col, nrows, 1).copyTo(dst.getRange(start_row, start_col), {contentsOnly: true})
```

Without `{contentsOnly: true}` the effect is equivalent to normal copy-paste, also carrying over formulas and formatting.  with `{contentsOnly: true}` it's equivalent to copy and paste-values-only. If additional rows or columns are needed in the destination, they will be automatically inserted.

Comment: One Caveat I found is that the copyTo functions only work in the same workbook. That said, this is a much more aesthetically easy to work with method.